# There is an error in XML document exception in kiosk mode

Tags: wpf, assembly, deserialization, kiosk, fody-costura

I'm developing an app for kiosk and I substituted `explorer.exe` registry address to my `app.exe`. When I want to work with XML file, the program throws an error:

> There is an error in xml document(0,0):

I even tried embedding dlls using Costura.Fody package but it didn't work as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've found the answer and I like to share it to everyone

because I have stopped windows default running explorer.exe , The program couldn't get access to default xml directory therefore weshould specify the complete xml's path for example like this:

```
stream = File.Open(@"C:\x86\Debug\xml.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```